# Como chamar novamente a função sem perder a promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promises

Sou iniciante ainda no Node.Js, e não sei como fazer essa operação. Na código abaixo da pra perceber que a função **readSubscriptions()** é chamada logo depois da função **login()**. Porém se ocorrer um erro no login() eu não faço nada para tratá-lo, eu queria chamar novamente a função login(), mas se eu fizer isso não vai dar problema na promise e acabar perdendo a sessão do meu login?

Tem algum jeito, ou padrão a se seguir em casos assim?

```js
let cs      = require('cloudscraper')
let promise = require('promise')

let login = function() {
    return new promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log("Logando...")
        cs.post("https://bj-share.me/login.php", {username: '****', password: '*****', keeplogged: true}, (err) => {
            if (err){
                console.log("Login falhou!\n")
                reject(err)
            } else {
                console.log("Login com sucesso!\n")
                resolve()
            }
        })
    })
}

let readSubscriptions = function(){
    return new promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log("Lendo página de seguidos...")
        cs.get("https://bj-share.me/userhistory.php?action=subscriptions", (err, res, body) => {
            if (err){
                console.log("Leitura falhou!\n")
                reject(err)
            } else {
                console.log("Leitura com sucesso!\n")
                resolve(body)
            }
        })
    })
}

login()
    .then(readSubscriptions)
    .then((res) => {
        if (res.indexOf("Nenhum post seguido foi atualizado.") != -1){
            console.log("Não há atualizações!")
        } 
    })
```

Comment: Queres que teste de novo caso o login falhe é isso? testa assim: https://jsfiddle.net/4vwoegmj/1

Comment: Opa, deu certo! Obrigado Sergio!

Comment: Boa! vou dar uma resposta então

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes usar o método `.catch()` das Promises para iniciar uma nova acção quando algo correr mal.

Se criares uma nova função com o que já tens podes chama-la dentro do `.catch` assim:

```
function ligar() {
    login()
        .then(readSubscriptions)
        .then(res => {
            if (res.includes("Nenhum post seguido foi atualizado.")) {
                console.log("Não há atualizações!")
            }
        }).catch(() => {
            setTimeout(ligar, 1000); // esperar um segundo e tentar de novo
        });
}
ligar();
```